# iOS 11.4 not asking Privacy Usage ( Privacy - Motion Usage Description has been set )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm stumped, iOS 11.4 ( 15F79 ), iPhone 6. Cannot get the App to Ask for Motion Data.  info.plist has been set via the editor and double checked via the info.plist open in textWrangler, Also deleted key and saved via textWrangler.

```
 <key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This app needs your Phones motion manager to update when the phone is tilted. Please allow this App to use your phones tilt devices</string>
```

I have deleted then reinstalled the app about 10 times. I have restared the phone 5 times.  I have checked through settings and my app does NOT show up in Privacy-Motion and Fitness or anywhere else in settings. I am using a free developer account, maybe that has something to do with it?

I created a new Xcode game template and changed nothing apart from importing CoreMotion and this code

****  Edited, sorry I forgot to say I had started the instance, just forgot to put it here, just in case someone thinks that's the problem ************

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

 motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

    if motionManager.isDeviceMotionActive == true {
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to:  OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {
        (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in
            let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
            print(accelerometerData)
        } as! CMAccelerometerHandler)
    }else{
        print(CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus().rawValue)
    }
```

which prints a 0 ( an Enum - case not determined ) to the console.

In my actual app it was a 3 ( same Enum - case Denied ).

As I've said, I have uninstalled, reinstalled, edited plist via Xcode and text wrangler ( a code editor ) , tried different versions of the code above, tried the code in different places ( in did move to view, in class )tried code off apple docs. etc.... I haven't been asked the NSUsage question and the App keeps crashing.

I have looked for ways to get the Alert fired up, As in CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() but I cannot find a comparable CMMotion version ( I don't think there is one. ) I have created a new swift file , imported Foundation and CMMotion and just put that code there, But still no Alert asking for Motion Data.

I tried a single view app template instead of a game template thinking that might be the issue, Nope.

What do I do?

Any help Appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two related but different classes.

`CMMotionManager` gives access to accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope data. It does not require any user permission as this information is not considered privacy related.

In your `else` clause you are checking the authorisation status of `CMMotionActivityManager`. This object reports the device motion type (walking, running, driving). This information is considered privacy related and  when you create an instance of this class and request data from it, the permissions alert is displayed.

The reason your `else` is being triggered is because you are checking `isDeviceMotionActive`; this will be `false` until you call `startDeviceMotionUpdates`, which you never do.  Even if you used `isAccelerometerActive` you would have a problem because you call `startAccelerometerUpdates` in the `if` clause which will never be reached.

You probably meant to check `isAccelerometerAvailable`. If this returns `false` then there isn't much you can do; the device doesn't have an accelerometer.

**Update**

It doesn't make sense to check `isDeviceMotionActive` immediately after calling `startDeviceMotion`:

1. You know it's active; you just started it
2. I imagine the start up takes some time, so you could expect to get `false` if you check immediately.

Apple recommends that you do not have more than one observer in place for each motion device type, so the purpose of check the `is...Active` to ensure you don't call `start...` again if you have already done so.

If you only want gyroscope data then you don't need to call `startDeviceMotionUpdates` at all.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I was calling start but I had missed it pasting code over. Accelerometer is Available ( true ) but no matter what I do I cannot get asked the question re Usage. Even this  **print(motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable)
  motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
  print(motionManager.isAccelerometerActive)** prints true then false

Comment: I wouldn't think it is valid to check the active state immediately after calling `start`; I would assume that it takes some time for the device to start

Comment: You got it, I put the check for **print(motionManager.isAccelerometerActive)** in TouchesBegan and it worked, I was calling it too fast. Added the start for **activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler:......** and up popped the Usage Question, It wasn't asking until I started it as it didn't need to. Thanks for your help.